# Replace for URL not found in twig

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to delete some part of my url (string) in twig, and I can not do it. The result is not that I expect:

`"http://local.myurl.com/en/node/8"|replace("en/node/8", "")`

I expect:

> "http://local.myurl.com/"

And the result is:

> "http://local.myurl.com/en/node/8"

Answer (score 2):

You can try json format like this :

```
{% set url = "http://local.myurl.com/en/node/8" %}
{{ url|replace({"en/node/8" : ""}) }}
```